# Jasmine - Checking addClass on click

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

This is a Rails app. I'm using the Jasmine gem with Jasmine-Jquery.

Here's my JS in asset pipeline:

```
$selector = function() {
    $('#filters li').click(function() {
        $('#filters li').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
}
$selector();
```

Here's my fixture called workgrid_spec.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <ul id="filters">
            <li class="identity" data-filter=".identity">Identity</li>
            <li>//</li>
            <li data-filter=".print">Print</li>
            <li>//</li>
            <li data-filter=".web">Web</li>
            <li>//</li>
            <li data-filter=".video">Video</li>
            <li>//</li>
            <li class="selected" data-filter="*">See All</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my spec file:

```
describe("Make sure the workgrid works right", function() {    
    beforeEach(function() {
        loadFixtures('workgrid_spec.html');    
    });    
    describe("when a filter is clicked", function() {   
        it("is highlighted in the list with the 'selected' class", function() {
            $('.identity').click();
            expect('.identity').toHaveClass('selected');
        });    
    });
});
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Expected '.identity' to have class 'selected'.
    at new jasmine.ExpectationResult (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:114:32)
    at null.toHaveClass (http://localhost:8888/__jasmine__/jasmine.js:1235:29)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/__spec__/workgrid_spec.js:12:24)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you `$selector` function is called before the fixture is loaded, so the event can't added to the element. You have to call the function in your test again or use jquerys `delegate` function to bind the event.

Answer (score 3):

As described by Andreas, you need to use your selector like so:

```js
it("is highlighted in the list with the 'selected' class", function() {
      $('.identity').click();
      expect($('.identity')).toHaveClass('selected');
});
```

remember to include JQuery in your specs as well, ie.

```js
var $ = require('jquery');
```